# Alter Organic Groups membership requests

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, organic-groups

I want to remove the option "Invite Only" from Membership Requests in Organic Groups.

I've tried to do a hook_form_alter but I've had not luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Using:
Drupal 6.16
Organic Groups 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some work on modifying/simplifying Organic Groups - here's the code on GitHub: http://github.com/voxpelli/drupal-og-enhanced/blob/master/og_simplemembership/og_simplemembership.module

Hopefully that helps a bit - there's some other modifications as well in the other modules in that repository - all open source of course :)

Comment: Thanks with a bit of tweaking this helped a lot.

It's also worth noting that you need to adjust the module weight so this is run after og has done it's stuff.